# Mime type for archive

Tags: javascript, servlets

I am trying to upload an archive file taken through `<input type=file>` in HTML, then calling servlet using javascript.

In javascript I am trying to get the **mime** type of it, but it is giving the type as ""(means empty). So how can I identify whether it is an archive?

Comment: please share relevant code, ie the function or `if` statement and the contents of it by editing your post.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there isn't one mime type for all archives, but each have their own (if they have one at all).

Have a look into [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_archive_formats) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for this, But I actually limit the file types to Zip,Tar and Rar . So Can U suggest me some method for that..

Comment: your question was the mime type, not the method... if you have found the mime type you were looking for through my answer, you may accept it as the correct one (click big check mark below voting buttons) and place another question about the method including the code you have tried and specifying where you failed...

Comment: Actually I am checking if(file.type==<list of mimeTypes>) and I am getting file.type="" when I am debugging the code.